# Node.js server, importing and exporting data to and from client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a node.js server and I have the code to get the server running. However, I am not sure how to get data from the client into to database. This is a game I am working on which I want to make multiplayer so I am new to node.js. Every player has a different picture on their screen and I am using javascript to draw on a canvas in my html file. How do I get information from the player and then query that to then give them an output to draw on their screen.

- Thank you the sooner this can be answered the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser client can do one of three things with a server.

1. It can request a new web page thus changing the active page in the browser (probably not what you're asking for).
2. It can send an ajax call to the server and receive a response from the server.  An ajax call can either be used just to send information to the server or it can be used to get information from the server and then display that information to the user by changing the currently displayed web page.
3. You can create a lasting webSocket connection to the server.  After the webSocket connection is created, then the server can send the client new data or requests or the client can send the server data or requests.  Data or requests can be sent either way.

If you just want to send from the web page to the server so that the server can store something in the database, then you would likely use the 2nd option (an Ajax call).  You would create a route in your node.js server (e.g. a specific URL for this Ajax call) and then from your client, you would make an Ajax request to that specific URL.  You can also send data or parameters to the server with the Ajax request.

Comment: Actually to be more specific I am making an agario spin-off so I need the client's mouse position and I need to ship data (such as other near by players) so that the client's screen can display the environment uniquely for that specific client. (if you don't know agario, http://agar.io/)

Comment: Is it possible to basically in my client's socket, give them the player code, and then keep the update file in the server and just have the client ship their x, y, and mass to the server; then have the update file send data to the client display code?

Comment: @IanS. - If you want to regular ship data back and forth between client and server, then you probably want to use a webSocket connection since it's the lowest latency way to regular send data either way.  If you want to be able to dynamically send data from server to client without the client having to poll for it, then a webSocket is your only choice.